# Why are the lower bounds different for the graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Q. For which values of n are these graphs regular?(from Rosen)

a) $Kn$ b) $Cn$ c) $Wn$ d) $Qn$

Sol : a)$ \forall n ≥ 1$   b)$ \forall n ≥ 3$  c)$n = 3$  d)$\forall n ≥ 0$

What is confusing me is that if for complete graph the bound is $1$, then why for n cube graph it is $0$? Is it something trivial?

Comment: Don't forget, $Q_0 = K _ 1.$

Comment: ah..got it! thanks! Should I delete this question now? Or if you wrote an answer I could accept. @user52969

Comment: You can answer yourself if you find the way to do it. Don't delete this question, can be useful for someone else :)
(Excuse me if my english is bad)